# Не получается разделить столбик в beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
url = 'https://www.rksi.ru/mobile_schedule'




buttom = requests.post(url, data={"stt":"Показать!", "group":"ИС-26"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(buttom.text, "html.parser")
rasp = soup.find_all("p")
for str in rasp:
    print(str.text.strip())
```

Вывод:

```
13:10  —  14:40Численные методыАрутюнян М.М., ауд. 325-1
15:00  —  16:30Элементы высшей математикиДжалагония  М.Ш., ауд. 323-1
16:40  —  18:10Численные методыАрутюнян М.М., ауд. 325-1
```

А нужно, чтобы выводило так:

```
13:10  —  14:40 Численные методы Арутюнян М.М., ауд. 325-1
15:00  —  16:30 Элементы высшей математики Джалагония  М.Ш., ауд. 323-1
16:40  —  18:10 Численные методы Арутюнян М.М., ауд. 325-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит потому что код элемента `p`:

```
<p>15:00  —  16:30<br><b>Элементы высшей математики</b><br>Джалагония  М.Ш., ауд. 323-1</p>
```

А свойство `text`:

```
15:00  —  16:30Элементы высшей математикиДжалагония  М.Ш., ауд. 323-1
```

Для того, чтобы вместо `<br>` появились пробелы можно сделать так:

```
url = 'https://www.rksi.ru/mobile_schedule'
buttom = requests.post(url, data={"stt":"Показать!", "group":"ИС-26"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(buttom.text, "html.parser")
rasp = soup.find_all("p")
for p in rasp:
    for br in p.find_all('br'):
        br.replace_with(' ')
    print(p.text)
```